# Where to save a program's config and save files on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, file, directory

What directory is the typical place to save files generated by a program, like a game or tool, when the file itself isn't necessarily useful on it's own?  (i.e it's *not* a "document" like a text file or image that you'd want easy access to, instead it's just a config or save file you'd want to tuck someplace out of the way)

Does this change depending on if a program is "installed", as opposed to an executable free-floating in a folder?  (For instance, is it standard practice to just save in the same folder in the latter case?)

If it's someplace that varies, is there a utility function I have to call to get a string of the path?

Comment: Maybe [this blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/) can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Known Folder IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) for a tip. Most likely, you want `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`. Use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) to retrieve the folder location.

Usually, I give the users the ability for "install" or "portable", in the latter case the app files goes into a folder under the portable installation folder.